# Как настроить URl каталога в меню Bitrix?

Tags: битрикс

Есть тип инфоблока: "Каталог товаров" и есть компонент "Меню".
Инфоблок: "Каталог товаров"

Если набрать url 
[http://madeirrf.beget.tech/сatalog/kurta-kurti/-](http://madeirrf.beget.tech/%D1%81atalog/kurta-kurti/-) то 404
Или перейти в какую-нибудь категорию каталога из меню - тоже самое

Но если перейти из кеша madeirrf.beget.tech/%D1%81atalog/?clear_cache=Y то категорию открывает
Также, есть переходы между категориями с этой страницы в разные разделы каталога (не из меню)

И при этом, адрес в начале или при копировании появляется такого вида: madeirrf.beget.tech/%D1%81atalog/kurta-kurti

но выглядит в строке вот так [http://madeirrf.beget.tech/сatalog/kurta-kurti/-](http://madeirrf.beget.tech/%D1%81atalog/kurta-kurti/-) 404

Шаблон каталога header.php

```html
<!--<?//if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>
<!--
Author: W3layouts
Author URL: http://w3layouts.com
License: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported
License URL: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <?php
    use Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset;
    $APPLICATION->ShowHead();
    ?>
    <!--объект апликейшн и метот title и вызываем метод ShowTitle-->
<title><?php $APPLICATION->ShowTitle(); ?></title>

<?php Asset::getInstance()->addCss(DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_PATH."/css/bootstrap.css");
      Asset::getInstance()->addCss(DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_PATH."/css/style.css");
      Asset::getInstance()->addCss(DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_PATH."/css/nav.css");
      Asset::getInstance()->addCss(DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_PATH."/css/form.css");
      Asset::getInstance() ->addJs(DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_PATH . "/js/jquery.min.js");
      Asset::getInstance() ->addJs(DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_PATH . "/js/hover_pack.js");
      Asset::getInstance() ->addJs(DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_PATH . "/js/jquery.easydropdown.js");
      Asset::getInstance() ->addJs(DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_PATH . "js/scripts.js");
      
      /*для подк.всего прочего*/
      Asset::getInstance()->addString('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">');
       Asset::getInstance()->addString("<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");
?> 

 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $(".scroll").click(function(event){  
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1200);
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
    <!--админ панель-->
        <div id="panel"><?php $APPLICATION->ShowPanel();?></div>
    
    
  <!-- header-section-starts -->
  <div class="c-header" id="home">
    <div class="top-header">
      <div class="container">
      <div class="logo">
           <a href="/"><img src="<?=DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_PATH;?>/images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="header-top-right">
        <!-- start search-->
            <div class="search-box">
              <div id="sb-search" class="sb-search">
              <form>
                <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Enter your search term..." type="search" name="search" id="search">
                <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" value="">
                <span class="sb-icon-search"> </span>
              </form>
            </div>
            </div>
          <!-- search-scripts -->
            <script src="<?=DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_PATH;?>/js/classie.js"></script>
            <script src="<?=DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_PATH;?>/js/uisearch.js"></script>
        <script>
              new UISearch( document.getElementById( 'sb-search' ) );
            </script>
          <!-- //search-scripts -->

          <a href="cart.html"><i class="cart"></i></a>
        </div>
          <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:menu", "menu_catalog", Array(
                 "ALLOW_MULTI_SELECT" => "N", // Разрешить несколько активных пунктов одновременно
                  "CHILD_MENU_TYPE" => "left", // Тип меню для остальных уровней
               "DELAY" => "N", // Откладывать выполнение шаблона меню
               "MAX_LEVEL" => "2", // Уровень вложенности меню
               "MENU_CACHE_GET_VARS" => "", // Значимые переменные запроса
               "MENU_CACHE_TIME" => "3600", // Время кеширования (сек.)
               "MENU_CACHE_TYPE" => "N", // Тип кеширования
               "MENU_CACHE_USE_GROUPS" => "Y", // Учитывать права доступа
               "ROOT_MENU_TYPE" => "main", // Тип меню для первого уровня
               "USE_EXT" => "Y", // Подключать файлы с именами вида .тип_меню.menu_ext.php
               "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "horizontal_multilevel"
              
         ),
     false
);?>
        
      
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- start Dresses-page -->
  <!-- content-section-starts -->
  <div class="container">
```

main.menu_ext.php (вкл.в комп.)

```html
<?php

if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
global $APPLICATION; 
$aMenuLinksExt = $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:menu.sections",
    "",
    Array(
        "IS_SEF" => "Y",
        "SEF_BASE_URL" => "/catalog/",
        "SECTION_PAGE_URL" => "#SECTION_CODE#/", /*адрес раздела меню/ "#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/"*/
        "DETAIL_PAGE_URL" => "#SECTION_CODE#/#ELEMENT_CODE", /*путь у товару конечному. полный путь  "#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/#ELEMENT_CODE",*/
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog",  /*тип информац.блока  id  записан http://madeirrf.beget.tech/bitrix/admin/iblock_type_admin.php?lang=ru*/
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "4", /*id каталога товаров http://madeirrf.beget.tech/bitrix/admin/iblock_edit.php?type=catalog&lang=ru&ID=4&admin=Y*/
        "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "2", /*уровень вложенности*/
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A", 
        "CACHE_TIME" => "3600" 
    )
);
$aMenuLinks = array_merge([['Home', '/', [], [], '']], $aMenuLinksExt, $aMenuLinks); /*$aMenuLinks это .main.menu.php - статичный arr.
чтобы контакты были вконце надо поменять местами arr. ссылка на home добавл.в виде []*/
```

[Url bitrix.catalog](https://habrastorage.org/webt/5c/7b/12/5c7b12e4c7862766810923.jpeg)

[url в админке](https://habrastorage.org/webt/5c/7b/12/5c7b12ed6ae15941116588.jpeg)

[404](https://habrastorage.org/webt/5c/7b/15/5c7b155779fe3831332404.jpeg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%D1%81atalog - это значит, латинская "c" прописана в русской раскладке, ищите в шаблонах адресов где написано с ошибкой, либо в инфоблоке каталога, либо в компонентах каталога или меню